# How to split a sentence(String) into arrays including spaces?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have to split my sentence into many small strings with a maximum of 10 characters per string including the white spaces using Regex and Js.

```
let S = "Pre demo edit to 21st Century";
let strArr = s.match(/.{1,10}/g);
```

expected:

```
["Pre demo ", "edit to", "21st", "Century"]
```

actual:

```
["Pre demo e", "dit to 21s", "t Century"]
```

Comment: What about `Pre demo123`?

Comment: including spaces the first 10 characters are **Pre demo e**

Comment: Instead of splitting, match using [`.{10}|.{1,10}$`](https://regex101.com/r/9Und1N/2)

Comment: @ellipsis OP wants a max of 10 characters, not 10 characters exactly

Comment: and how about `1234567891011`? What is expected?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you want to get spaces because in the first position of your expected array have one.

let me know if is this that you need.

```js
let s = "Pre demo edit to 21st Century";
let strArr = s.match(/.{1,10}\b/g);
let res = document.getElementById('res')
res.innerHTML = strArr

console.log(strArr)
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted - seems to do exactly what OP is wanting

Comment: @Pete I don't know either... I'm waiting if he need without spaces...

Comment: @Pete I think you should add `1234567890` to the beginning and see the results.

Comment: @revo still seems to work with that - the only limitation I see is if you have a word that is longer than 10 characters, it gets sliced to 10 characters but as OP hasn't stated what should happen in that scenario I still think this is ok

Comment: @Pete Still seems to work? I see `123` is missing in results.

Comment: @revo only if you add 2 more characters to that string and that is covered in my second bit to the comment above

Comment: @Pete Yes and that makes problems. OP never put boundaries on input string.